# How to trigger hyperlink click even - react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react component I am trying to trigger a click on the hyperlink created in the below function:

```
  getUsers(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const { userIds } = this.props;
    BatchRoleActions.getAllRoleUsers(userIds)
    .then((users) => {
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.setAttribute('id', 'csvLink');
      link.setAttribute('download', 'roles.csv');
      link.setAttribute('href', users);
      document.getElementById('csvLink').onClick();
    });

  }
```

When the function is run I get the below error :
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'onClick' of null

How can I trigger click to start my download?

BatchRoleActions.getAllRoleUsers(userIds) returns an an array with data for export to a csv file.  encodeURI(`data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,\uFEFF${data}`);

I am trying to find a solution for: [ReactJs - How to complete onClick before download - href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554776/reactjs-how-to-complete-onclick-before-download-href)

Comment: You spelled `OnClick` wrong with a capital O, but we need more information to help you

Comment: You haven't inserted it into the DOM. Anyways, don't mix native DOM methods with React...

Comment: Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit1: I misunderstood what the OP asked for, edited my answer now!
Edit2: More edits after reading OP's link

I've set up a sandbox to mock what you're trying to do; take a look at it here - https://codesandbox.io/s/18k6oppy2l

**Pay attention to the `Users.js` file**

1. We'll put a visible `button` and an invisible `<a>` tag in the DOM
2. When the user clicks on the `Download User data` button, the request to retrieve the `users` is made
3. Once the request resolves to string representation of the users data, we call `setState` to set the user in the state
4. In the `setState` callback, we then programatically "click" the invisible `<a>` tag to download the `users.csv`; this will trigger the download of the file

Comment: I am trying to export data to a csv file. atchRoleActions.getAllRoleUsers(userIds) returns an an array with data for export to a csv file. encodeURI(data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,\uFEFF${data});

Comment: My bad, misunderstood what you were asking for. I've edited my answer now, please take a look at it!

Comment: I do not wish to get user data on render . i wish to populate my href with the data onClick from a buttton then call the getUsers function and start download. Please see the link in my original question

Comment: edited my answer again, now fetching the data on a button click and then triggering the download (by providing a callback to the the `setState` call)

Comment: Hi Raghudevan. Thanks. I am starting a new exciting project and need 3 react  developers . Would you be able to join. How can I contact you?

Comment: cool, link to the project on github? you can write to me - raghudevan@gmail.com